# Tablet Driver Doesn't Work Unless I re-plug the tablet and relog

Tags: drivers, tablet

I have a uc-logic (athene m) tablet and I installed the digimend drivers to make it work. The tablet starts working fully only if I replug its usb cable and relog.

If I just replug the cable it starts working but gimp doesn't see it. But relogging after that makes everything work.

Is there a way to fix this?